# progress of extracting zip file using c#

Tags: c#, zip

i have a program in c# that needs to extract epub file

epub file is a zip file

to i have this code for extracting the zip file

```
                string zipPath = filename;
                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
                {
                    archive.ExtractToDirectory(epubPath);
                }
```

but the problem is how can i check if all the files are already extracted using c#

after the files are extracted i need to process the file. so i need to check the status of the extraction to avoid some bugs. thank you

Comment: Once your extraction completes, the files are extracted.. unless your code doesnt work. It should error should it fail to extract

Comment: so you mean i can use try and catch with finally? without having possible bugs? i mean ill execute the code to process the file on finally?

Comment: Define "bugs" .. if you extraction completes without issue the files are there, if there are issues your files may not be there.. you may need to do something to tidy up.. You may also find files are not available for immediate opening if an antivirus has the files open to check them..

Comment: Besides try-catch block, you can use File.Exists method to check if file is in destination directory. After files are extracted, check for existence like this. `if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(epubPath, "yourFileName.ext"))) { /* it exists, continue with your code... */}`